# Word from an Australian speaker

Tags: word-request

This is a request for a few words (from an Australian speaker) I can't make out in a Youtube video.

Here is my transcript below, with the passage I didn't get in question marks.

> This person, who is clearly a very stable, solid, family man, with a good career, and .. ????

The passage starts around 17:43 at https://youtu.be/gGuqXEo6soY?t=1063s

It sounds like "he risal his pectin in garlics (or Gaelics)"
My guess would be that the meaning is something like "He's raising all his children in Gaelic" but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker has a tendency to rush and to elide some syllables. However, the key words that you're missing are:

> ... he's raised all these practicing Catholics.

In context, he's talking about his father-in-law, who has/had 10 children, all of whom remained in the Catholic church in a time when the speaker was seeing many of his peers fall away from the church. (The context starts back around 14:50.)

Comment: Thanks. By the way, even Youtube's automatic subtitler seems confused by the speaker's rushing and eliding as you say, in this particular passage

Comment: Alos, sorry for not being (yet) able to upvote your useful answer

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure and don't listen all video to get context, but

**he is raised all these practices and (?gathering?)**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It would certainly be a whole lot better guess if it even made any sense. What's the point of posting an answer that cannot possibly be correct?